# Updating a table with the result of a query on 2 other tables

Tags: sql

I need to update a column on a table with the a value that is a result of another query. However, the customerid column on the receiving table needs to be matched to the customer id column on the query.

Here is my query so far:

```
INSERT INTO PaymentFacilities
(PolicyId)

(SELECT        c.Id, p.PolicyId
FROM            Customers c INNER JOIN
                     Policies p ON c.Id = p.CustomerId
WHERE        (NOT (p.PolicyReference IS NULL) AND p.Cancelled = 0))
```

In the example above I want to insert the p.PolicyId field from the select query into the PolicyId column of the PaymentFacilities table but only where the CustomerId field of PaymentFacilities matches the c.Id field from the select query.

Thanks for your help

Comment: And what doesn't work? Error message?  Also, that is an insert and not an update....

Comment: Ah yes, with a bit more thinking I came up with: UPDATE pf 
  SET pf.PolicyId = p.PolicyId
  FROM dbo.PaymentFacilities AS pf
  INNER JOIN dbo.Customers AS c
  ON pf.CustomerId = c.Id
  INNER JOIN dbo.Policies AS p
  ON c.Id = p.CustomerId
WHERE (NOT (p.PolicyReference IS NULL) AND p.Cancelled = 0)

Comment: Have you tried it? Errors etc?

Answer (score 0):

The number of columns in the `select` statement should be the same as the `insert` statement.

You could try removing all columns except `p.PolicyId1`:

```
INSERT INTO PaymentFacilities
(PolicyId)

(SELECT        p.PolicyId
FROM            Customers c INNER JOIN
                     Policies p ON c.Id = p.CustomerId
WHERE        (NOT (p.PolicyReference IS NULL) AND p.Cancelled = 0))
```

Keep in mind this will insert multple rows, and every time you run the query you will also have duplicates.

If you describe the whole problem I'm sure people can help you find a better solution.